# ffmpeg video overlay between not responding to timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, video, ffmpeg

Just cant get ffmpeg to overlay png at the desinged time. I tried all the options and its always displaying in wrong times.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call([
    'ffmpeg',
    '-y',
    '-i', 'out_1.mp4',
    '-i', 'overlay.png',
    '-filter_complex', "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,0)",
    '-codec:a','copy',
    'out_2.mp4'
])
```

When I change between(t,0,0) its display in second from 0 to 10. I need this to display in second from 0 to 1 of the video. The video total duration is 50 seconds.
Here is the screen recording to show my problem

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnFG1F172uU&ab_channel=KevinBestReviews

Comment: Your exact command with `'between(t,0,1)'` worked as advertised (showing the overlay for only the first 1 second). Clarify which command produced which wrong times.

Comment: 'between(t,0,1) show overlay png between second 0 and 10. That's the problem

Comment: You are missing a single quotation mark, in the between argument - `"[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,1)'",` should do the trick

Comment: This did not solve the problem, still overlay.png showing between second 0 and 10

Comment: You don't mention your `os` but using the command I gave in a previous comment, works as expected on Linux Ubuntu/Mint. The image shows for just 1 second at the start.

Comment: Also works in Windows FYI